# SQL Query for Best Intersection of Items

Tags: mysql

I am writing an order fulfillment system in using a MySQL Server which pre-packaged boxes have been filled with items and I need to determine which, if any, combination of boxes to ship to satisfy an order. I am unsure what SQL tools are available to me to efficiently solve query for the boxes required.

An table of order items looks like the following, if I had order 1 be for a fork and spoon:

```
mysql> select * from order_items;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | name  | order_id |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | fork  |        1 |
|  2 | spoon |        1 |
+----+-------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

while the boxes are arranged as

```
mysql> select * from boxes;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | box1 |
|  2 | box2 |
|  3 | box3 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> select * from items;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | box_id |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | spoon |      1 |
|  2 | knife |      1 |
|  3 | fork  |      1 |
|  4 | knife |      2 |
|  5 | fork  |      2 |
|  6 | spoon |      3 |
|  7 | knife |      3 |
+----+-------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, there is a problem. It could be that boxes may contain an individual fork and another an individual spoon, or both in one box. However,  in this case I have boxes with all three utensils, or a mixture of each. It is expected that, in general, a single box will not cover all the requirements for the order but it is acceptable to send a box with extra items if needbe. In this case, a single box would work OR the combination of the other two available boxes. In either case one or two extra knives would be sent. Ideally, we would like to send the minimal number of extra utensils but we do not care about the number of boxes.

What is the appropriate query to efficiently determine what combination of boxes will work? I do not know of a single query, but I think that a series of queries that try and find a match for all N items, then N-1, then N-2 until a match is found and then repeat for the remaining items. This seems fairly inefficient, though.

Edit:

The problem is to find a subset of all boxes `B_S` such  `m_i` is a member of `B_S` for all items  `m_i` in order `M`.

Comment: So if you have three types of utensils, you would want a total unique combo of utensils per box? Something like box1=spoon, box2=spoon x 2, box3= spoon x 3, box4 =spoon+fork, box5= fork x 2?

Comment: The boxes are already filled, they just have to be selected. An order may be for a set of all utensils or any subset of them.